# Margin 0 in header, nav

Tags: html, css, margin

Setting `margin: 0` doesn't in `header{}` or `nav{}` but works as expected in `ul{}`. I thought that `ul{margin:0}` would not not work since `header` and `nav` are parents.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Compañía</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css"> </head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Purchase</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    height: 420px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[Link to example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10dov.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's because the margin you're seeing is coming from the `ul`, not the `header` or `nav`. Both `header` and `nav` have 0 margin already by default, so adding `margin: 0;` to either of them will do nothing. A `ul`, however, has default margin that is applied by the browser, so setting `ul { margin: 0; }` removes that default margin.

You're seeing the margin of the `ul` outside the bounds of it's parent(s) because of [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

> If there is no border, padding, inline content, block_formatting_context created or clearance to separate the margin-top of a block from the margin-top of its first child block, or no border, padding, inline content, height, min-height, or max-height to separate the margin-bottom of a block from the margin-bottom of its last child, then those margins collapse. The collapsed margin ends up outside the parent.

Comment: I think that the margin of "ul" should not affect their parents.

Comment: @eag845 it's called "margin collapse." Updated my answer.